# how to display images in a larger view port irrespective of any resolutions without affecting the quality in HTML?

Tags: html

I have a few images to display. The images have to be displayed on a larger viewport. But the resolutions of the image are affecting the display. The images with more width are getting displayed very nicely but the images with more height are getting stretched.

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="img/produce_img/8-turmeric-868187035471289-1544677646857_micro_4.jpg" alt="user" style="width:100%;height:auto">
</div>
```

All the images are having inline CSS of width 100% and height auto

Resolution 1:-
Width : 858px
Height: 217px
The image display is large and very clear.

Resolution 2:-
Width : 256px
Height: 611px
The image display is large, but the screen size is increased a lot vertically.

Resolution 3:-
Width : 72px
Height: 178px
The image display is large, but the image quality is stretched out.

Any idea how to display the images largely irrespective of any resolution without affecting the quality?

Comment: Technically there are many solutions to this. But we need to know, what you are trying to achieve in more detail.

Comment: @yunzen I just need to display few images in a larger viewport irrespective of any resolution. The problem is the smaller resolution images are getting stretched and affecting the quality. so making width 100% is creating a problem for the images which have less resolution and more height, for e.g:- Resolution 2 and Resolution 3

Comment: Please post a fully working code example. You can use dummy images like https://picsum.photos/.